# Create Link to level up controller using Razor in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

This is my code that i'm using to create a link to top level link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit",Url.Action("Edit","Home", new{row.Application_ID})) 
// supposed to return /Home/Edit/x (application_id)
```

Instead, it returns:
    **/Home/Home**/Edit/x   // Current View is Home/Edit

Please help.

**Edit 1:**
Route Table information:

```
//This is for Edit 
routes.MapRoute(
           "Edit", // Route name
           "Home/Edit/{application_id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Edit", application_id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        // This is the default route, I've modified it to LogOn.
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a small edition to haim770 answer. if you want for some reason use `Url.Action` instead `Html.ActionLink` you are always free to write it like that:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { application_id  = row.Application_ID })">Edit</a>
```

Some developers prefere this way because it more similar to plain Html, but result is the same as Html.ActionLink

Comment: thanks for your reply, that I already have tried from the discussion with @haim770. it returns the application_id as in query string, I want to pass it a fraction.

Comment: @Sunny It is strange, because you have special route for it, which is absolutly normal and should work. May be in your controller action parameter is from uppercase: Application_ID instead of application_id?

Comment: @Andrey-Gubal: true, I tried a work around and it did the trick. i used double dot to refer to parent and now it's working fine as expected. See my answer on that, really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner `@Url.Action`, try this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Home", new { application_id  = row.Application_ID }, null);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, tried that, now it's giving me the link with application_id in query string, like:
     /Home/Edit?application_id=x
.
I want it to be:
/Home/Edit/x

Comment: Then you'd probably want to try this (assuming you're using the default routing and your `Edit` action expects a parameter named `id`): `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Home", new { id = row.Application_ID }, null);`

Comment: thanks, but this also returns the link as /Home/Edit?id=x, I do not want any query string, this is why I was trying to use Url.Action inside.

Comment: Show your routing table, and the signature of your `Edit` action.

Comment: please see Edit 1 in question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38533/discussion-between-sunny-and-haim770)

Answer (score 0):

tried this work around and it worked:

```
<a href="..@Url.Action("Edit",new{application_id})">Edit</a>
```

now it returns the link as **Home/Edit/x**  :)